# YACC/LEX call the parser from C file

Tags: c, yacc, flex-lexer

For a project I use yacc and lex/flex to parse a file, and I'd like to call the parser from somewhere else than from the `.y` or the `.l` files.

I can call the `yyparse()` function, but if I just do that, it will read from `stdin`, so I have change `yyin` to make it refer to my file. But I can't access it somewhere else than in the `.l` file.

In the flex man page I saw the option `--header-file=lex.h` who seems to be like the `-d` for yacc, but when I use it I have an error:

```
lex: can not open --header-file=lex.h
/usr/bin/m4:stdin:2837: ERROR: end of file in string
```

So how can I access to `yyin` in my program, or is there an easier solution to call the parser ?

EDIT:

I tried to put `extern FILE * yyin;` at the top of the `.l` file, but it does not work.

EDIT 2:
It works when I add it in the C file.

EDIT 3:
My flex version is 2.5.39, and the command line I use is:
`lex carnet.l --header-file=lex.h`

Comment: possible duplicate of [in lex how to make yyin point to a file with the main function in yacc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796520/in-lex-how-to-make-yyin-point-to-a-file-with-the-main-function-in-yacc)

Comment: OK, now that I can see your command line, I edited the answer to explain why that command doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to just declare it in the file where you need to use it:

```
extern FILE* yyin;
```

For the `--header` option to work, you need to put it before the source filename:

```
flex --header-file=lex.h carnet.l
```

because although flex implements long options, it does not conform to GNU style in which options may appear after positional arguments.

Comment: My version of flex is 2.5.39, and it seems to be the latest.

Comment: @phantom: how are you invoking it, then? Are you sure that `lex` on your system invokes `flex`?

Comment: @phantom: Also, I clarified my answer. You declare `yyin` *where you use it*.

Comment: What can invoke lex else ? And how can I know if lex invokes something else ?

Comment: @phantom: You could start with `lex --version` and see if it says 2.5.39. Other useful tools: `which lex` and `readlink` (to resolve the likely symlink). If all that checks out, put the *exact* command you used to invoke flex *into your question*.

Comment: lex call `/usr/bin/` who is an alias to `/usr/bin/flex`. So, yes I think lex invokes flex.

Comment: @phantom: then you are invoking it incorrectly. But if you don't show your command line, no-one can help you.